# How to convert individual chars to set integers for a basic password hasher, C++

Tags: c++, string, hash

I'm making a password hash for some uni work, which requires me to take an inputed string, convert the characters in it into integers (given a=1, b=2, c=3, ect.) and output the sums.

This is what I have so far: a function which will return an int, which uses a string from which to convert to the integer. But I'm already coming accross some errors just trying to build this, and I have no idea how to proceed from here regarding the conversion of the characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int passHasher(string tempPassword)
{
    int hashValue = 0; //function will return this at the end of the passes.
    for (int i = 0; i < tempPassword.size; i++) 
    {
        //hashing algorythm goes here.
    }
}
```

Cheers,

Owen.

Comment: int char_value = tempPassword[i] - 'a' + 1

Comment: Characters have [numeric values](http://www.asciitable.com/). For example, `tempPassword[i] - 'a'` will gives you the offset from `a` of each character in `tempPassword`.

Comment: _But I'm already coming accross some errors just trying to build this_ And you didn't include the error messages.. Why?

Comment: If you want help with the compiler errors, you need to copy and paste them here and indicate which line causes each error.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, characters can be manipulated as their numerical value. So for example, you can do something like:

```
char c = 'x';
int n = c - 'a'.
```

Here, I used 'x' as an example. For any lowercase letter, `n` will be a number between 0 and 25, inclusive. If you want 1 through 26 instead, just add 1.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you can't compile this code is the fact that you don't have a main function defined. After you add that in you will get an error with the "size" method. Size is a method, therefore you need () at the end.

The following code compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int passHasher(string tempPassword)
{
    int hashValue = 0; //function will return this at the end of the passes.
    for (int i = 0; i < tempPassword.size(); i++) 
    {
        //hashing algorythm goes here.
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // get the string fromt the input and call function
}
```

I removed windows.h since I was using Linux. Feel free to add that in when compiling on Windows.